# Tips on how to install laminate over existing flooring

Tags: stairs, laminate-floor

Currently I'm at the point where my laminate reaches the stair nosing and I'm unsure what to do.

[image]

[image]

I have a stair nosing piece but I'm finding that it's awkward looking.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated

Picture with nosing

[image][image]

Comment: How about a picture of the awkward nosing piece in place.

Comment: Hi, I've updated it

Comment: I am curious, did you consider refinishing the existing wood floor to your new color choice?

Comment: @Jack  It does look like a great floor to be covering over.

Comment: @JACK, you know, if the second floor is red oak parquet, the treads will solid red oak too. Still highly valued at least to me. Sorry if this is out of context with the OPs question.

Comment: They do sell stair refinishing pieces that are made to wrap around the edge of an existing tread. Here is [one example](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Cap-A-Tread-Sterling-Oak-Gray-Birch-Wood-47-in-Length-x-12-1-8-in-Deep-x-1-11-16-in-Height-Vinyl-Overlay-for-Stairs-1-in-T-016073691/205055533).

Comment: @jphi1618 what do you do around the pickets with it?

Comment: "Awkward looking" is in the eye of the beholder, and there's no actual question here. VtC

Answer (score 1):

I would cut a 3/4" strip of flooring and use some construction adhesive to fasten it to the edge of the stair and install the stair nose up against it with some adhesive. That won't expand and contract like the flooring might. Then fit the perpendicular pieces snug up against the back edge of the nose or underneath it if it's designed to overlap a bit. You might need a drop or two of adhesive on a few of those members to hold them down at the edge of the nose. Good luck.

Comment: Hi, when you say cut 3/4" of the flooring, are you specifically referring to the current nose that's there or the new nose?

Comment: @Master  I was suggesting the strip of the laminate that would go on the edge of the existing stair so when the new nose was installed, you wouldn't see the old edge as shown in the second picture.

Answer (score 0):

With it being such a short piece, you might try using some quarter-round and sanding the flat side of it down until the thickness matches that of the new floor. Since the floor is dark, perhaps just some dark caulk in the gap around the post would be sufficient. Are you planning to re-finish the stair post/balusters to match the new floor?

Comment: Yup. Taking out the carpet and staining